# hosting a react.js site on heroku - error H10 no

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment

We want to deploy a react.js app on heroku. The deploy-process works properly but when I start the view of the site we get the following error- output.
This are our app credetials:

- Procfile: web: npm start or web: react-scripts start
  We tried both.
- Buildpacks:
  https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack
  https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs#latest

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/LU4r7.png)